# Enumerating a list in a thread-safe way

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Let's say I have a list in a class which will be used in a multi threading scenario.

```
public class MyClass
{
     List<MyItem> _list= new List<MyItem>();
     protected object SyncRoot { 
      get {
         return ((IList)_list).SyncRoot;
        }
     }

     public void Execute1()
     {
        lock(SyncRoot)
        {
             foreach(var item in _list) DoSomething(item);
        }
     }

     public void Execute2()
     {
         Item[] list;
         lock(SyncRoot)
         {
            list=_list.ToArray();
         }
           for(var i=0;i<list.Length;i++) DoSomething(list[i]);
      }
}
```

The method **Execute1** is the 'normal' way to enumerate the list in a thread-safe way. But what about **Execute2**? Is this approach still thread-safe?

Comment: No, Execute2 is unsafe if MyItems are reference types (objects), as the list and array both point to the same objects ultimately.

Comment: @Will That's not a problem in this specific scenario as I'm concerned only about the list itself. The objects can handle sync themselves if it's required.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know I can use any object, but I'm wondering if it's better to use the list's sync object. I mean that's why it's exposed, no?!

Comment: This site has an awesome set of chapters on multi-threading: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe as long as every other use of `_list` is also protected with the same `lock` statement. You are taking exclusive access to the list, copying its contents and then working on the copy (to which you also have exclusive access due to scoping). A bit wasteful at first sight, but a legitimate approach under certain circumstances.

Comment: Yes, add/remove items from list are made using the same lock. However I don't quite grasp why the local list automatically gets exclusive access.

Comment: @MikeSW: Because it's out of scope for everyone else except method `Execute2`.

Answer (score 2):

Access to the (copy of the) List is threadsafe in both scenarios. But of course the MyItem elements are not synchronized in any way.

The second form looks a little more expensive but it will allow Add/Remove on the original while the `DoSomething()`s are running.  The array acts like a kind of snapshot, if that matches your requirements it could be useful. Note that you might as well use `ToList()`.